# Does Cutting Planes solve Pigeongole Principle for holes of different sizes?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques

Suppose a problem:

> Given $n$ pigeons and $m$ holes of sizes $b_{i\le m}$ decide if you can put all pigeons in given holes.

It's possible to find a refutation of size $\mathcal O(n^2\log^2 n)$ of this principle when it's encoded as a conjunction of threshold functions, therefore there must exist a polynomial size Frege refutation any time $n>\sum_{i=1}^m b_i$.

However, is Cutting Planes too weak already to have a polynomial size refutation for the $n=1+ \sum_{i=1}^m b_i$ case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_{ij}$ state that pigeon $i$ goes to hole $j$. One can axiomatize the pigeonhole principle as follows:

1. Booleanity: $0 \leq x_{ij} \leq 1$.
2. Pigeon axioms: for all $i$, $\sum_j x_{ij} \ge 1$.
3. Hole axioms: for all $j$, $\sum_i x_{ij} \le b_j$.

Summing the pigeon axioms, we get
$$
\sum_{ij} x_{ij} \ge n.
$$
Summing the hole axioms, we get
$$
\sum_{ij} x_{ij} \leq m.
$$
Therefore $n \leq m$, which is a contradiction if $m < n$.

You might be interested in other encodings of the pigeonhole principlethey can probably be used to derive the axioms above.